# how can i remove all digits before some specific digit

Tags: c++

How can i remove all digits from number before finding specific digit.
Let's say i want to get all digits after  digit 1 (1-included)

Example: 3543125 -  i want to get digits 125

i started doing this:

```
int n, result;
    cout << "Please enter number: ";
    cin >> n;
    while (n>0)
    {
        n = n % 10;
    }
```

to get last digit, but i don't know how you can save it in variable and then add the second digit to it.

Can someone please explain, how can i solve this?

Comment: Everything following, and including the `1` is simply `n %= 1000;`. The result is `n` has the value `125`. No loop is required. So, what problem are you *really* trying to solve?

Comment: @WhozCraig this will not work correctly, it must be completed with loop, if lets say you enter 314, you will get same output but not 14

Comment: You sure that there is a 1 in the number? or you need to check it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an algorithm I didn't test it but it works {only with loops and if}

```
int num = 3543125;
int temp = 0;
do             //get the result in reverse number
{
    temp += num % 10;
    temp *= 10;
    num /= 10;
    if (num % 10 == 1)
        temp += 1;

} while (num % 10 != 1);    
int result = 0;
while (temp > 0)   //reverse the temp number to result
{
    result = result * 10 + (temp % 10);
    temp = temp / 10;
}
cout << result;  // = 125
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. (too simple :-) )

```
 #include <math.h>
    int n,a, result=0;
        cout << "Please enter number: ";
        cin >> n;
        cout << "Please enter number of digits: ";
        cin >> a;
        int b=a;
        while(b>0) {
             result += n%10 * pow(10,a-b--);
             n=n%10;
        }
        std::cout<<"result: "<<result;
```

Comment: i have to do it only with knowing the number and not using string

Comment: Then convert the number to string with std::to_string.

Comment: That correctly cuts off the last n digits (although `n % pow(10,a)` does the same in a single line), but it doesn't find a digit and establish how many digits to cut.

Comment: Don't use `pow` for integer values.  `pow` is a floating point function.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: **Good** catch.  One would need to write an `ipow` function too.